# row_number error in firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

I want to write this query in my sql

```
SELECT ID, row_number() over() FROM FORMUL order by ID DESC
```

but ı get an error.

> Error : Dynamic sql error :Token unknown - line 1, column 29 (

What can I do for this error?

Answer (score 7):

Firebird 2.5 and earlier do not have window functions (which includes `row_number`). The parser thinks that `row_number()` is some UDF or internal function (existence of said function is checked later), and considers `over` an alias, the `(` after `over` is then unexpected and therefor a syntax error.

Window functions have been added to Firebird 3. You can download Firebird 3 at http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-3-0/

See also ["Window (Analytical) Functions" in the release notes](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs.html).